# Nutch 2.2.1, Hbase 0.90.4 and Hadoop 1.2.1 session timeout

Tags: hadoop, ant, hbase, apache-zookeeper, nutch

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.blogjava.net/paulwong/archive/2013/08/31/403513.html) and I get stuck when I tried to inject urls to nutch from hadoop. I configured nutch files like this [tutorial](http://nutchhadoop.blogspot.sk/) by copying hadoop conf files to nutch conf directory. When I tried to run ant runtime with configured files according to the first tutorial, it did not work.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-238:~/apache-nutch-2.2.1/runtime/deploy$ bin/nutch inject urls
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

15/07/27 12:01:07 INFO crawl.InjectorJob: InjectorJob: starting at 2015-07-27 12:01:07
15/07/27 12:01:07 INFO crawl.InjectorJob: InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: urls
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.3.2-1031432, built on 11/05/2010 05:32 GMT
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=master
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.6.0_45
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/lib/tools.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/..:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/aspectjtools-1.6.11.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-daemon-1.0.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/hadoop-capacity-scheduler-1.2.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-1.2.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/hadoop-thriftfs-1.2.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.12.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jdeb-0.8.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/junit-4.5.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-2.1.jar:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=3.2.0-75-virtual
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=ubuntu
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/ubuntu
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/ubuntu/apache-nutch-2.2.1/runtime/deploy
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
15/07/27 12:01:10 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x14ecf53dd5f0007, negotiated timeout = 180000
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: how many nodes in your cluster?

Comment: one master and two slaves

Comment: So use  hostname or IP address of your nodes instead of localhost in the configuration

Comment: I changed everything to IP adresses, also changed some configuration files. It run every nutch command except nutch elasticindex elasticsearch -all but it is different problem. Thank you very much :-)